# How to insert into ReportServer.DBO.Subscriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver

SQL Server 2005 
Report Server

How can a subscription be manually created?

ReportServer uses the proc CreateSubscription to add a row to the Subscriptions table.

I have a new shared schedule.  The reports that subscribe to an existing schedule, need to also subscribe to the the new shared schedule, using all the same attributes (the difference between the schedules is one is timed, and the other will be called from code).

The issue I see is generating a SubscriptionID (unique identifier).  It's not set as a primary key, so I  can't just leave it out as a parameter for an insert statement.

Is there a way to use the same method for generating the subscription id that ReportServer uses, or can I generate my own guid, or will I be reduced to recreating these subscriptions manually...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can generate a fresh guid with the newid() function.

Comment: Thats's true -- and I'm testing with that, but since the Subscriptions table is essentially a system table for Report Server I want to be especially careful.

Comment: I'll post more after testing.

Comment: So yes -- technically speaking, I can use NewID() to create a guid, and a row can be inserted into the Subscriptions table.  A corresponding row must also be added to ReportSchedule table, which means one would want to hold on to the newly created guid for Subscriptions to use in ReportSchedule.